# How to create new cluster in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have installed elastic search on my ubuntu system and it's working fine with default cluster.
But i want to create another cluster.
I have checked official document of elastic search but i haven't found any steps for create another or multiple cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update `ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml`. Under the cluster section, change the cluster name parameter.

```
cluster.name: my_cluster
```

Default value for cluster name is `elasticsearch`

**One instance of ES can be a part of only one cluster.** If all ES instances / machines have the same cluster name, elasticsearch will form a cluster automatically as long as the machines are all on the same network

Comment: it will replace elasticsearch cluster, i want both cluster. as you said One instance of ES can be a part of only one cluster. it's not possible multiple instance on same ES

Comment: One ES instance is one node and it cannot be part of different clusters. However, you may run multiple ES instances on the same machine https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-i-run-multiple-elasticsearch-nodes-on-the-same-machine/67