# How to connect to ES cluster locally made using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I just started to learn `Elasticsearch` and `Spring Data Elasticsearch` with a demo project and I was able to get up and running.

Installed `Elasticsearch` on Mac using `brew install elasticsearch` and started it using `brew service start elasticsearch`.

For the project,

```
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories(basePackages = "com.shubham.entities")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.shubham")
public class DataConfig {

private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataConfig.class);

@Value("${elasticsearch.home}")
private String elasticsearchHome;

@Bean
public NodeBuilder nodeBuilder() {
    return new NodeBuilder();
}

@Bean
public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate() {
    try {
        final File tmpDir = File.createTempFile("elasticsearch_data", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));
        final Settings.Builder elasticsearchSettings =
                Settings.settingsBuilder().put("http.enabled", "true")
                        .put("index.number_of_shards", "1")
                        .put("path.data", new File(tmpDir, "data").getAbsolutePath()) // 2
                        .put("path.logs", new File(tmpDir, "logs").getAbsolutePath()) // 2
                        .put("path.work", new File(tmpDir, "work").getAbsolutePath());

        return new ElasticsearchTemplate(nodeBuilder()
                .local(true)
                .settings(elasticsearchSettings.build())
                .node()
                .client());

        // @formatter:on
    } catch (final IOException ioex) {
        logger.error("Cannot create temp dir", ioex);
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }
}
}
```

`elasticsearchHome` in above config file is actually empty, I wonder why is this still working. In `application.properties` file,

```
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=shubham_lookup_cs_default
spring.data.elasticsearch.repositories.enabled=true
```

I am able to perform CRUD and other DB operations through Spring Data JPA and tested it as well, works good.

My question is, how can I query it through command line?

When I use `curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'`, I get back:

```
{
  "name" : "4IVQcts",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_shubham",
  "cluster_uuid" : "WxCAzE51TfS7P4eFYJpvCA",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.3.0",
    "build_hash" : "3adb13b",
    "build_date" : "2017-03-23T03:31:50.652Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.4.1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Clearly, not the expected one as `cluster_name` is `elasticsearch_shubham` which is default I guess.

What I am thinking is that I am missing something very basic here. 2 different clusters exist on my machine now.

For more info about how I know that `elasticsearch` project is working, I made some entities and persisted them, queried using Controllers, working.

So, I have the following questions:

1. How do I connect through the cluster made by `Spring Data Elasticsearch` through command line, using CURL?
2. Is there any User Interface through which I can see all data in `elasticsearch`, maybe using `Kibana`?
3. Is `Spring Data Elasticsearch` actually using the default cluster, instead of the cluster name I mentioned in `application.properties` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Clearly, not the expected one as cluster_name is elasticsearch_shubham
>   which is default I guess.

Actually if you want your cluster with name  'shubham_lookup_cs_default'
than you need to update ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml

```
cluster.name: my_cluster
```

Default value for cluster name is elasticsearch
If you want two cluster , than I am not sure if we could create two . Check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42927266/how-to-create-new-cluster-in-elasticsearch) .

> How do I connect through the cluster made by Spring Data Elasticsearch
>   through command line, using CURL?

I am not sure , If spring data elastic search will create Cluster . Spring data elastic will just point to existing cluster .
If you want to run cluster than  just do :-

```
cd elasticsearch-5.3.0/bin/
./elasticsearch
```

> Is there any User Interface through which I can see all data in
>   elasticsearch, maybe using Kibana?

Yes Kibana is there for real time analytics . It will show all data in Discover Tab . Just click on Discover  :-

[image]

> Is Spring Data Elasticsearch actually using the default cluster,
>   instead of the cluster name I mentioned in application.properties
>   file?

Might be 'shubham_lookup_cs_default' is not present in ES_HOME/config/elasticsearch.yml . Check if not present than update ,than surely it will point to 'shubham_lookup_cs_default'

Comment: For the last point, I checked in `elasticsearch.yml` and made it point to same path as `spring.data.elasticsearch.properties.path.data` in my Spring project. But now, I am unable to start the Elasticsearch through CLI but the project is running fine. Exception is `IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[<path>]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing`. Clearly, a lock is maintained.

How can I maintain the same data across CLI and Spring Data project?